# Update app with firebase database android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     myRef = database.getReference("Update");

    // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            if (value.toString() == "1.0")
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "No Update" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Need Update" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Failed to read value." + error.toException() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

value is 1.0 and string in if is 1.0 but when i run the app show me need update, why is that? i want hem to show me update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing string with `==` operator. It will return true if and only if both reference point to the same object.

Use `String.equals` to compare strings.